# My fragment isn't removed from my fragment container, despite fragment replacements working

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

My code contains a method in `MainActivity` called `changeFragment()`, which I use to replace and remove fragments in my two fragment containers. When I try I use this method to replace a fragment in a container with another, it works, but when I try to remove a fragment, it doesn't. No error in the Logcat is shown, and the code continues after I call this method, but the visuals for the fragment aren't removed even though I can no longer interact with the buttons within the fragment.

This is my `changeFragment()` method:

```java
public void changeFragment(String fragmentContainer, String fragmentRequested) {
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

    if (Objects.equals(fragmentRequested, "None")) {
        // Find the fragment to remove
        Fragment fragmentToRemove;
        if (Objects.equals(fragmentContainer, "menu")) {
            fragmentToRemove = fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.menucontainer);
        } else {
            fragmentToRemove = fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.selectioncontainer);
        }

        if (fragmentToRemove != null) {
            transaction.remove(fragmentToRemove);
        }


        // If a fragment replacement is requested:
    } else {
        // Find the new fragment to replace the old one with
        Fragment fragmentToBeDisplayed = switch (fragmentRequested) {
            case "CardNumberSelection" -> FragmentCardNumberSelection.newInstance();
            case "GameCreation" -> FragmentGameCreation.newInstance();
            case "Guide" -> FragmentGuide.newInstance();
            case "PlayerSelection" -> FragmentPlayerSelection.newInstance();
            case "Settings" -> FragmentSettings.newInstance();
            case "TitlePage" -> FragmentTitlePage.newInstance();
            default -> null;
        };

        // Replace the old fragment with the new one
        assert fragmentToBeDisplayed != null;
        if (Objects.equals(fragmentContainer, "menu")) {
            transaction.replace(R.id.menucontainer, fragmentToBeDisplayed);
        } else {
            transaction.replace(R.id.selectioncontainer, fragmentToBeDisplayed);
        }
    }

    transaction.commit();
    if (fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.menucontainer) == null) {
        findViewById(R.id.settingsmenu).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        findViewById(R.id.guidemenu).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        findViewById(R.id.settingsmenu).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        findViewById(R.id.guidemenu).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
}
```

Here is the code which is meant to remove the old fragment (`FragmentGameCreation`) from the fragment container (`menucontainer`) but doesn't. This line of code is in a method in MainActivity:

```java
changeFragment("menu","None");
```

This is the code I use to show `FragmentGameCreation` to begin with, which successfully replaces my `FragmentTitlePage` with `FragmentGameCreation` when I click a button in my title page fragment. This code is in my `FragmentTitlePage` class:

```java
// Start Game
startGameButton.setOnClickListener(view -> {
   // Replace the title page fragment with the game creation fragment
   FragmentManager fragmentManager = requireActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
   fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.menucontainer, frag, "menuTag").commit();
});
```

I have ensured using a debugger that all the intended lines of code are being run, and all are.

I have also tried to create the new instance of `FragmentGameCreation` globally before putting it into menucontainer, and using the `dindFragmentByTag()` method as a replacement for `findFragmentByID()`, but neither have solved this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error was caused by code later on in the application, by a while-loop which was designed to wait for a button to be pressed before exiting. Removing this while-loop solved the issue, and let the fragment be removed as intended.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add transaction.addToBackStack(null) to ensure that the fragment is removed completely

```java
if (fragmentToRemove != null) {
    transaction.remove(fragmentToRemove);
    transaction.addToBackStack(null); 
}
```

Comment: I added this line of code, but unfortunately it did not solve the issue.